# Creating Class Stopwatch Python. Don't Understand Why it Works?

Tags: python, windows

```
import time #useful for measuring code execution

class StopWatch:
    def __init__(self, startTime = 0, endTime = 0, elapsedTime = 0):
        self.__startTime = startTime
        self.__endTime = endTime
        self.__elapsedTime = elapsedTime

    def start(self):
        self.__startTime = time.clock()

    def stop(self):
        return self.getElapsedTime()

    def reset(self):
        self.__startTime = 0
        self.__elapsedTime = 0

    def getstarttime(self):
        return self.__startTime

    def getendtime(self):
        return self.__endTime

    def getElapsedTime(self):
        elapsedTime = self.__elapsedTime
        elapsedTime +=((time.clock() - self.__startTime) * 1000)
        return elapsedTime

def main():
    x = StopWatch()
    x.start
    a = time.clock() #code only works with this line of code in place (I don't understand why?)
    sum = 0 
    for i in range(1 , 10000000):
        sum += i
    x.stop
    print("Elapsed execution time is", x.getElapsedTime())
    print(sum)
    x.reset

 main()
```

The code fails to produce the correct result if I remove the
    a = time.clock()
portion. With that in place it produces the correct result but I am not really sure why it does this? 
I realize there may be better ways to do this, but Im kind of a beginner at Python so I'd appreciate the help. Thanks! I am using a Windows system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wouldn't happen to be a rubyist, would you? `x.start` works to call methods in Ruby, but not in Python. You need `x.start()` - notice the parentheses. You have the same problem with `x.stop` and `x.reset`.

`a = time.clock()` is helping because `time.clock()` will sometimes (platform-dependent) return the time *since the first call to `clock()`*, instead of from process start. The actual assignment to `a` isn;t doing anything, it's simply creating a start point for `clock` to reference later. Don't rely on this - the Python docs state "Return the CPU time or real time **since the start of the process *or* since the first call to clock()**."

Comment: It doesn't return the time since the *last* call to `clock()` on any platform. On Windows, it returns the time since the _first_ call to `clock()`. Which is what makes it work here. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html#time.clock).

Comment: thanks so much guys! it works now! and thanks for the promptness of the reply as well!

Comment: i have noticed there is some variaiton in the result, and based on reading this seems to be normal, many people say that an average of the time returned is the way to go, i think. Ill do some more reading but if you can point me to the right direction its appreciated! Ohh and I am not a rubyist that just incompetence there on my part, lol!

Comment: There will be natural variance due to irregularities in CPU operation (might be throttled down more at some points due to heat, cache may behave differently, etc). There's no real way to do averaging with a single run - instead, you would run your function/program many times, and average the `clock()` times for every run.

Comment: Even better: do several sets of multiple runs, average each set, then return the minimum of those averages; that's what the standard Python [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/timeit.html) module does. To quote: "In a typical case, the lowest value gives a lower bound for how fast your machine can run the given code snippet; higher values in the result vector are typically not caused by variability in Python’s speed, but by other processes interfering with your timing accuracy. So the min() of the result is probably the only number you should be interested in."